# Multiprocessing a loop

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a script that loops over a pandas dataframe and outputs GIS data to a geopackage based on some searches and geometry manipulation. It works when I use a for loop but with over 4k records it takes a while. Since I have it built as it's own function that returns what I need based on a row iteration I tried to run it with multiprocessing with:

```
import pandas as pd, bwe_mapping

from multiprocessing import Pool
    
#Sample dataframe
bwes = [['id', 7216],['item_id', 3277841], ['Date', '2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'], ['start_lat', -56.92], ['start_lon', 45.87], ['End_lat', -59.87], ['End_lon', 44.67]]

bwedf = pd.read_csv(bwes)

geopackage = "datalocation\geopackage.gpkg"
tracklayer = "tracks"

if __name__=='__main__':
    def task(item):
        bwe_mapping.map_bwe(item, geopackage, tracklayer)
    pool = Pool()
    for index, row in bwedf.iterrows():
        task(row)
    with Pool() as pool:
         for results in pool.imap_unordered(task, bwedf.iterrows()):
            print(results)
```

When I run this my Task manager populates with 16 new python tasks but no sign that anything is being done. Would it be better to use numpy.array.split() to break up my pandas df into 4 or 8 smaller ones and run the for index, row in bwedf.iterrows(): for each dataframe on it's own processor?
No one process needs to be done in any order; as long as I can store the outputs, which are geopanda dataframes, into a list to concatenate into geopackage layers at the end.
Should I have put the for loop in the function and just passed it the whole dataframe and gis data to search?

Comment: So is the program hanging? Have you tried putting print statements in the `task` function to see if it's being invoked and what is happening in it? `task` doesn't return anything, so the `print(results)` will just always print`None`.

Comment: Thanks, I added print statements after each for loop and with Ahmed AEK's answer I got passed this issue. The issue you pointed out I'm still not passed; the def task() is just their to feed the constant variables to the bwe_mapping.map_bwe() function within there it returns several geodataframes and 2 string lines. Do I need to add something to the def task() to get my outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are running on windows/macOS then it's going to use `spawn` to create the workers, which means that any child **MUST** find the function it is going to execute when it imports your main script.

your code has the function definition inside your `if __name__=='__main__':` so the children don't have access to it.

simply moving the function `def` to before `if __name__=='__main__':` will make it work.

what is happening is that each child is crashing when it tries to run a function because it never saw its definition.

minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def task(item):
        print(item)
        return item

    pool = Pool()

    with Pool() as pool:
        for results in pool.imap_unordered(task, range(10)):
            print(results)
```

and the solution is to move the function definition to before the `if __name__=='__main__':` line.

**Edit:** now to iterate on rows in a dataframe, this simple example demonstrates how to do it, note that iterrows returns an index and a row, which is why it is unpacked.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

# Sample dataframe
bwes = [['id', 7216], ['item_id', 3277841], ['Date', '2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z'], ['start_lat', -56.92],
        ['start_lon', 45.87], ['End_lat', -59.87], ['End_lon', 44.67]]

bwef = pd.DataFrame(bwes)

def task(item):
    time.sleep(1)
    index, row = item
    # print(os.getpid(), tuple(row))
    return str(os.getpid()) + " " + str(tuple(row))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool() as pool:
        for results in pool.imap_unordered(task, bwef.iterrows()):
            print(results)
```

the `time.sleep(1)` is only there because there is only a small amount of work and one worker might grab it all, so i am forcing every worker to wait for the others, you should remove it, the result is as follows:

```
13228 ('id', 7216)
11376 ('item_id', 3277841)
15580 ('Date', '2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z')
10712 ('start_lat', -56.92)
11376 ('End_lat', -59.87)
13228 ('start_lon', 45.87)
10712 ('End_lon', 44.67)
```

it seems like your "example" dataframe is transposed, but you just have to construct the dataframe correctly, i'd recommend you first run the code serially with iterrows, before running it across multiple cores.

obviously sending data to the workers and back from them takes time, so make sure each worker is doing a lot of computational work and not just sending it back to the parent process.

Comment: This got me going, thanks! But it still won't iterate over the dataframe I feed it. How do I make the dataframe iterable? I tried bwedf.iterrows() but thats not working for what are obvious reasons to me now.

Comment: @PassTheBeets i added an example code for iterating on sending a row of the dataset to the workers and sending it back, i'd recommend you look into your dataframe structure though as this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Yes I noticed that last night and fixed my example df; I'm often importing from csv and not making df from code input. I misunderstood how those inputs made a df so I got it a little backwards.

Comment: I also came up with a solution last night where I split the work amongst available processors using np.array_split to split up the df; your solution looks simpler and streamlined, I will try and implement it. My solution has the problem where I cannot break my outputs up to export to files. The output of bwe_mapping.map_bwe are a list, or series, of dfs from panads and geopandas. I need to pass each df to their own respective lists to merge\concate and export to a file. I'm hoping using your solution will solve this for me :D! Thanks again for the help

Comment: this is working for me, I had to change the return from return str(os.getpid()) + " " + str(tuple(row)) to return bwe_mapping.map_bwe(row, data, layer) then add a partial_task = functools.partial(task, data=tc_source, layer=trackslayer) then feed that to the for as for results in pool.imap_unordered(partial_task, bwedf.iterrows()): and that returns a iterable object containing the 5 dataframes I can call individually as results[x]