# multiprocess loop (python)

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

i have a dataframe which i'm trying to use multiprocess to use the available cores more efficiently for loops. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185743/multiprocessing-a-loop), however, i can't work out how 'pool' is applied.

sample df code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mac':['type_a','type_a','type_a','type_a','type_a','type_b','type_b','type_b','type_b','type_b'],
    'con':['a','a','a','c','b','a','a','b','a','c'],
    'result':[1,1,2,2,3,1,1,3,1,2],
})

MAX_NUMBER = 3 
for j in range(MAX_NUMBER):
    
    i = j + 1 
    aft = f"mc{i}_aft"
    bef = f"mc{i}_bef"
    
    holder1 = ['con', 'mac', 'result']
    holder2 = ['con', 'mac']
    df['add'] = (df.groupby(holder1).cumcount() + 1)
    df[aft] = df['add'].loc[df.result == i]

    df = df.groupby(holder2, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0))

    df = df.drop(['add'], axis=1)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df[aft] = df[aft].astype('int')
    
    df[bef] = df.groupby(holder2)[aft].shift(1)
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df[bef] = df[bef].astype('int')
```

sample df:

```
╔═══╦════════╦═════╦════════╗
║   ║  mac   ║ con ║ result ║
╠═══╬════════╬═════╬════════╣
║ 0 ║ type_a ║ a   ║      1 ║
║ 1 ║ type_a ║ a   ║      1 ║
║ 2 ║ type_a ║ a   ║      2 ║
║ 3 ║ type_a ║ c   ║      2 ║
║ 4 ║ type_a ║ b   ║      3 ║
║ 5 ║ type_b ║ a   ║      1 ║
║ 6 ║ type_b ║ a   ║      1 ║
║ 7 ║ type_b ║ b   ║      3 ║
║ 8 ║ type_b ║ a   ║      1 ║
║ 9 ║ type_b ║ c   ║      2 ║
╚═══╩════════╩═════╩════════╝
```

sample output:

```
╔═══╦════════╦═════╦════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   ║  mac   ║ con ║ result ║ mc1_aft ║ mc1_bef ║ mc2_aft ║ mc2_bef ║ mc3_aft ║ mc3_bef ║
╠═══╬════════╬═════╬════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 0 ║ type_a ║ a   ║      1 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 1 ║ type_a ║ a   ║      1 ║       2 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 2 ║ type_a ║ a   ║      2 ║       2 ║       2 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 3 ║ type_a ║ c   ║      2 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 4 ║ type_a ║ b   ║      3 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║       0 ║
║ 5 ║ type_b ║ a   ║      1 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 6 ║ type_b ║ a   ║      1 ║       2 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 7 ║ type_b ║ b   ║      3 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║       0 ║
║ 8 ║ type_b ║ a   ║      1 ║       3 ║       2 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
║ 9 ║ type_b ║ c   ║      2 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
╚═══╩════════╩═════╩════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

ps. actual df is much larger and involves more variables and loops, hence, trying to fully utilize the available cores to save processing time. The loop is groupby/cumcount of results before(bef) and after(aft) tests.

kindly advise

Comment: The loops' iterations are not independent. The result of an iteration is built on that of the previous one. I don't think you can process them in parallel. What you could do, is to partition the data by groups, then process the groups in parallel.

Comment: @QuangHoang, thank you for your reply. The iterations are based on "result"(1,2,3). Which to my understanding is independent of each other. Processing the groupby cumcount of 2 shouldn't require the results from 1 or 3. The only part isn't independent is the before/after process which is within the same iteration.

Comment: Obviously not, your operations acts on the whole dataframe, not just the `df.results == i` parts, based on the `fillna(0)`...

Comment: @QuangHoang, thank you for the clarification. Makes sense now. Will try to find examples of how to partition the data by groups and process them in parallel.